# Working example for Erlang Server Interface

Tags: erlang, cgi, inets

I am trying to make Erlang's Inets mode_esi  work and run some function.  So, far, I did not succeed.  Can someone post a minimal example of how to run Inets so that a url like `http:localhost:8099/esi/my_mod:foo` will invoke the method `my_mod:foo/3`?

Addition: I have started inets with these commands:

```
inets:start(),
inets:start(httpd, [{port, 8099}, {server_name, "localhost"}, {document_root, "."}, 
  {server_root, "."}, {erl_script_alias, {"/esi", [my_esi, io]}}]).
```

The module is:

```
-module(my_esi).
-export([foo/3]).
foo(Sid, Env, In) -> mod_esi:deliver(Sid, ["bla"]).
```

But browsing to `http://localhost:8099/esi/my_esi:foo` result in an error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved it myself.  For some reason, beyond my understanding, the exact same code worked when I invoked Inets with a configuration file (a modified version of `inets/examples/server_root/conf/8080.conf`).  I suppose that the example file includes a more complete list of properties that Inets required than what I listed in `inets:start(httpd, [...])`.  If anyone encounters Inets problem in the future, my advice is to start with the example configuration.

Answer (score 2):

To clarify what has already been said, I'll give a working example (from the ground up).  This is to help those who came here from google, mostly because it's how I found it ;)

First, create the module:

```
# filename: my_esi.erl
-module(my_esi).
-export([foo/3,bar/3]).
foo(Sid, Env, In) -> mod_esi:deliver(Sid, ["foo"]).
bar(Sid, Env, In) -> mod_esi:deliver(Sid, ["bar"]).
```

Save it, then compile it:

```
erlc my_esi.erl
```

You'll now have my_esi.beam

Then run the shell from bash

```
erl
```

Within the shell type the following:

```
inets:start().
{Httpd_State,Httpd_Pid} = inets:start(httpd, [{port, 8099}, {server_name, "localhost"}, {document_root, "."}, {modules,[mod_esi]},{server_root, "."}, {erl_script_alias, {"/esi", [my_esi, io]}}]).
```

The important part here is:

```
{modules,[mod_esi]}
```

If you need other modules, load them by appending them to the list.

To clarify how/why:

I will first admit that it does seems a bit strange at first, and that the documentation was less helpful than I had hoped.  However, I realised that:

```
modules()       -> [atom()]
```

becomes:

```
{modules, [mod_access, mod_esi, ..., etc.]}
```

Hope it helps someone :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here goes:

1. set `{erl_script_alias, {"/esi", [my_mod]}}` for the `inets` web server, so the module is accepted.
2. Write `my_mod`. Something like:

   ```
   -module(my_mod).
   -export([foo/3]).


   foo(SessID, _Env, _Input) ->
     mod_esi:deliver(SessID, ["Data ", <<"as">>, " an iolist"]).
   ```
3. Make sure `mod_esi` is part of `inets` section called module: `{modules, [.., mod_esi, ..}}`
4. This step is very important: Breathe 3 times, recite the holy words "I pray to thee, inets, that you will work this time". Cross your fingers.
5. Drink a cup of coffee. Tea will not do. It has to be coffee.
6. Enjoy your web server.

Comment: I updated the question with the not-working example.  What am I doing wrong there? Seems like a simple version of what you wrote.